# Repeat-x doesn't work - css

Tags: html, css

I have one problem with repeat-x. My css code is this:

```
#header {
}

#header_left {
background:url("../img/header_l.png") no-repeat;
float:left;
width:341px;
height:258px;
}

#header_content {
background:url("../img/header_c.png") repeat-x;
width:32px;
height:258px;
float:left;
}

#header_right {
background:url("../img/header_r.png") no-repeat;
float:right;
width:341px;
height:258px;
}
```

And html code:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="header_left"></div>
        <div id="header_content"></div>
        <div id="header_right"></div> 
    </div>
```

But image header_c.png repeats only once. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo0JW.png , header_c.png is repeating once and then leaving empty space.

Comment: What do you mean with 'is repeat once'?

Comment: `#header_content { width:32px; }` - seems narrow.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Without the original images it's almost impossible to see the symptoms...

Comment: also, can you provide al ink the actual image you are using, as it would be useful to see if it has whitespace that could be affecting this

Comment: What are the dimensions of `header_c.png`?

Comment: That is problem ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mo0JW.png

header_c.png is repeat once and have empty place.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant `repeat-y`, looking at the dimensions of the HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your error is that between the central and right blocks obtained by the gap. You can fix this by setting the right block `float: left` or change width of center block.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvZkX/3/) - my example with your error.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvZkX/4/) - fix with `float: left`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvZkX/5/) - fix with exact size of center block

Comment: That is problem ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mo0JW.png

header_c.png is repeat once and have empty place.

Comment: Width of your center block is 32px. You show a screen where the central block is the same width (32px). Try to change the width of the central block and you will see how header_c.png tile the entire block

Comment: Why to change central block size, Central block alone must be repeated??

Answer (score 0):

**May be you should try this**

```
#header {
margin: 0 auto;
height:auto;
width:auto;
padding:0px;
}

#header_left {
background:url("../img/header_l.png") no-repeat left top;
width:341px;
height:258px;
}

#header_content {
background:url("../img/header_c.png") repeat-x left top;
width:32px;
height:258px;
}

#header_right {
background:url("../img/header_r.png") no-repeat left top;
width:341px;
height:258px;
}
```